# "Failed to instantiate one or more classes" Android Studio proyectos nuevos

Tags: android, android-studio

La verdad no sé como catalogar el error, instalé el Android Studio por primera vez en este equipo y me sale este error (Imagen), la verdad desconozco por qué, se supone que hice una instalación normal.

[image: Cuando inicio un proyecto me sale esto]

Al final de la descripción del segundo mensaje sale esto: 
Exception Details java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.view.View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener

Si alguien me puede ayudar lo agradecería mucho

Como dato extra que se me olvidó colocar, en los archivos XML no puedo visualizar el design debido a esto, por eso es que me urge solucionarlo. Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que se ve en la imagen el problema está al cargar el ActionBar del AppCompact. El ActionBar se llama en el archivo styles.xml, que está dentro de la carpeta values en res, la ruta es res/values/styles.xml. Acabo de comprobar como se llama al ActionBar en mi Android Studio, en mi caso lo hace así y no me da ningún error, comprueba que tu también lo tengas así:

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
</style>
```

En ese archivo también tendrás las etiquetas resources y algunos items para los colores, pero en la que se llama al ActionBar es en style y es en la que posiblemente tengas algo diferente por lo que te surge el error.

Comment: si tengo la misma, al final lo solucioné pero como una especie de medida parche, cuando te vas al archivo XML (al design), hay un menú llamado AppTheme y en ese hago click y selecciono "Holo Light". Y se arregla, pero despues vuelve a la forma predeterminada, al menos es funcional y me deja trabajar, pero no deja de ser molesto estarlo haciendo cada cierto tiempo.

Comment: Como has dicho esa solución te puede servir durante un tiempo para seguir trabajando, pero es mejor que encuentres una solución definitiva, si puedes pon el código de tus archivos styles.xml y activity_main.xml en tu pregunta, para ver si el error está ahí.